# Merging two files based on a common column

Tags: linux, shell

I have 2 files one is the ouput of telnet command and another is ip and host file. I want to merge these two files based on common ip.

file1:

```
25-08-2019_22.00.03 : Port port1 of URL http://ip1:port1/ is [ NOT OPEN ]
25-08-2019_22.00.03 : Port port2 of URL http://ip2:port2/ is [ NOT OPEN ]
```

and file 2 is:

```
http://ip1:port1/cs/personal, CS
http://ip2:port2/cs/Satellite/out/, CS_SAT
```

and a want an output file like below:

```
25-08-2019_22.00.03 : Port port1 of URL http://ip1:port1/ is [ NOT OPEN ] : CS
25-08-2019_22.00.03 : Port port2 of URL http://ip2:port2/ is [ NOT OPEN ] : CS_SAT
```

I am no expert in linux, any help is highly appreciated.

I tried join option like join -o file file2, but it does not give desired output.

I tried awk command like creating key value pair for 1st file and running over 2nd file, but it does not give any ouput, is it ecause of sepatarors or special characters in files ?

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next}{if(a[$1]==""){a[$1]=0};
    print $1,$2,a[$1]}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cut` and `paste`:

```
paste -d " : " file1 <(cut -s -d ',' -f2 file2)
```

This joins both file line per line with `:` in between.

The second file is modified to only have the second part of line based on the comma `,`.

Comment: Hi, It works fine but I am facing issue with non matched entries. i.e. if file2 has more entries like:                                                                    
http://ip1:port1/cs/personal, CS
http://ip2:port2/cs/Satellite/out/, CS_SAT                  http://ip3:port3/cs/Satellite/out/, ED, it also appends the "ED"  at the end of file along with matching entries. Is there anything we can do to join only matching ips ?                                                                 it

Comment: Hi Oliv, this command works as command line option, but when I try to run this command in .sh file, I get error : syntax error near unexpected token `(' > below is the content of script in which I am using command:              
 #!/bin/bash
paste -d " : " wo_br.log <(cut -d ',' -f2 ip_names.txt) >merged_file.log. I tried using " around parenthesis, but it does not work, any help please ?

Comment: @Novice It's hard to guess with just what you describe... Please ask another question with the full details of the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have to preprocess the input files in some way. First, extract the common field using some regexes with `sed`, then `join`. After that you have transform the output to match your expected.

Comments in code:

```
# recreate input
cat <<EOF >file1
25-08-2019_22.00.03 : Port port1 of URL http://ip1:port1/ is [ NOT OPEN ]
25-08-2019_22.00.03 : Port port2 of URL http://ip2:port2/ is [ NOT OPEN ]
EOF
cat <<EOF >file2
http://ip1:port1/cs/personal, CS
http://ip2:port2/cs/Satellite/out/, CS_SAT
EOF

# join on the first field
join -t' ' -11 -21 <(
  # extract the part inside `http://<here>/` and put it in front of the line
  # ip1:port1 25-08-2019_22.00.03 : Port port1 of URL http://ip1:port1/ is [ NOT OPEN ]
  <file1 sed -r 's@^(.*http://([^/]*).*)$@\2 \1@' | sort
) <(
  # extract the part inside `http://<here>/` and remove all the we are not interested in
  # ip1:port1 CS
  <file2 sed -r 's@http://([^/]*)/.*, (.*)@\1 \2@' | sort
) |
# ip1:port1 25-08-2019_22.00.03 : Port port1 of URL http://ip1:port1/ is [ NOT OPEN ] CS
# remove the leading ip1:port1
cut -d' ' -f2- |
# replace the trailing ` CS` with ` : CS`
sed 's/[^ ]*$/: &/'
```

Comment: HI Kamil, is it mandatory to give input of file in script, I mean the input varies time to time. Can we not just give input as files ? Please input will be helpful.

Comment: Then where from the input comes from? Replace the `<file1` for redirection of the first file and `<file2` for redirection of second file. They can be fifos, not plain files.

Comment: Thanks Kamil for prompt inputs, the input comes from file only. I will try the redirection as suggested, but for the above script, which actually worked for the first time is now giving me error " sh -x merge_files.sh
+ cat
+ cat
merge_files.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
merge_files.sh: line 12: `join -t' ' -11 -21 <('
"

Comment: The file uses `bash` extension, ie. `<(..)` process redirection. You can't run it under `sh`. You can rewrite it to work under `sh` tho, create two fifos, redirect the output of `sed` + `sort` to `fifos` and then `join` the `fifos`. Also make sure your file has unix line endings `dos2unix` and that you don't start your script with `#!/bin/sh`, but `#!/bin/bash`...

Comment: Thanks Kamil, I will try this.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, being a early learner, I can not really understand more on like using fifos and join. I tried replacing #!/bin/sg with #!/bin/bash, but still same issue. Thanks a lot for help.